# Webflux-Aop:Get method request(Mono) in Aspect class

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-aop

I am trying to write an aspect which is responsible to call some external systems, before calling service impl classes.

I have difficulty getting method request in aspect class.Any help would be appreciated. I tried to write as below ,but no luck getting Mono Object in aspect class.

**Method**

```
@someAnnotation
@PutMapping
fun getAccounts(
    @RequestParam(name = "someParam")
    someParam: String?,
    @ModelAttribute
    request: Mono<Request>,
): Mono<Response>{
        return response;
    }
```

**Annotation**

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class someAnnotation(
    val api: String,
)
```

**Aspect:**

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(0)
class SomeAspect{
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    @Around("@annotation(someAnnotation)&&args(req,..)")
    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    fun <T> getResponse(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint,apiReq : Mono<T>): Mono<T> {
        
        val target = joinPoint.target
        val methodSignature = joinPoint.signature as MethodSignature
        val method: Method = methodSignature.method

        val flux: Mono<T> = joinPoint.proceed() as Mono<T>
        val methodArgs = joinPoint.args

//How to get request: Mono<Request> here????
        
        return flux.flatMap { it ->
            val req = it as someObject
           //do something here........
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try this please ? modify the pointcut as `@Around("@annotation(someAnnotation)&& args(req,..)")` and then the advice as `fun <T> getResponse(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint, req : Mono<Request> ): Mono<T>` . You should be able to get the parameter in `req` reference.  I am a java person and this is based on how I read your Kotlin code.

Comment: the idea is to add an argument to point cut , reference the same in the advice method

Comment: Tried this ,but got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: req [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName].  on application start up

Comment: Could you please update the question with what you have tried. This exception happens when there is argument mismatch.

Comment: Either keep `args(apiReq,..)` or `req : Mono<T>)` and retry . The pointcut arg and the method arg names should match

Comment: This time app started ,but aspect is not invoked.I think this is because request method has two method params.How can we pass only required request to aspect, if the method call has multiple arguments.

Comment: try `args(someParam,apiReq)` and `(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint,someParam :String? ,apiReq : Mono<T>)`

Comment: Can't we eliminate someParam since i don't need it?

Comment: If the previous one worked , then we are on the right track . You can try `args(..,apiReq)` and `(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint,apiReq : Mono<T>)`

Comment: Did that resolve your issue ? Any updates ?

Comment: Yes that resolved my issues.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following modification to the aspect code would solve the issue. The OP want to advice a method with multiple arguments and the required argument to be made available to the advice body would be the last argument.

Summarizing the resolution through comments here.

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(0)
class SomeAspect{
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    @Around("@annotation(someAnnotation) && args(..,apiReq)")
    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    fun <T> getResponse(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint,apiReq : Mono<T>): Mono<T> {
        
        val target = joinPoint.target
        val methodSignature = joinPoint.signature as MethodSignature
        val method: Method = methodSignature.method

        val flux: Mono<T> = joinPoint.proceed() as Mono<T>
        val methodArgs = joinPoint.args


        //.. apiReq will refer to the required argument
        return flux.flatMap { it ->
            val req = it as someObject
           //do something here........
        }
    }
}
```